# sending USSD Code with special character in android

Tags: android, kotlin, ussd

I want to send `USSD` code with @ symbol in android kotlin

like `*121*1*name@domain#`

but android ignore after @. it only sending `*121*1*name#`

```
val ussdCode = "*121*1*name@domain#"
telephonyManager.sendUssdRequest(ussdCode, callback, Handler())
```

Comment: sendUSSDRequest treats the request as a USSD code.  It supports only 0-9, *, #, and p (pause).  It doesn't send text messages, and definitely doesn't support the @ sign.  I'm not sure why you think it should, they don't even support text.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the special character and append with the string. use `Uri.encode("special character");`

for your code you can use like -

```
val ussdCode = "*121*1*name" + Uri.encode("@")+ "domain" + Uri.encode("#");
```

I have not tested but Hope this will help you.

Comment: if we send like this, its sending name40 only